# Google Map Not Rendering Correct Location

Tags: google-maps, dotnetnuke

We are using the following code inside a DotNetNuke 6.0 skin:

```
<iframe width="310" height="226" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?  f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=Howell+Sand+Co+INC++2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108,+United+State+of+America+(806)+383-1721&amp;daddr=&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=ddw0&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
<br />
<small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=embed&amp;saddr=Howell+Sand+Co+INC++2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108,+United+State+of+America+(806)+383-1721&amp;daddr=&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=ddw0"
style="color: #0000FF; text-align: left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

In it's current state, a map is rendered on the page.  However, the location it renders is not the correct address.  Please see the current behavior [here](http://temp.i360designsite.com/Home.aspx)

I've read further on the static map API and am wondering if the above should be re-written to invoke that API? Or, is there a different approach we should take?

Update:
I've re-written the javascript as follows:

```
function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.249369, -101.807561)
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover ", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(" < html > < body style = \"font-size: 8px;\"><table><tr><td align='left'><b>Company:</b> </td><td>Howell Sand Co Inc.<br/></td></tr>" + "<tr><td style=\"vertical-align:top;\"><b>Address:</b> </td><td>2300 East Hastings Avenue,<br/> Amarillo, TX 79108 (806) 383-1721 </td>" + "</tr></body></html>");
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
initialize();
});
```

Unfortunately, the map won't render at all at this point.  What must be done to modify the above code to render the correct map and location?

Comment: What do you mean "it is not the correct address"?  If I type that [URL into my browser](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Howell+Sand+Co+INC++2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108,+United+State+of+America+(806)+383-1721&hl=en&ll=35.250175,-101.804552&spn=0.056074,0.076218&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=49.624204,79.013672&mra=ls&t=m&z=14&iwloc=ddw0), it looks correct to me (although I haven't been to Amarillo, TX, so I can't say for sure).

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  The map renders but it does not plot the address correctly.  That is, the map is ploting the address in a completely different state.

Comment: What address is it plotting in what state?

Comment: Please see the newly-added link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map on [that page](http://temp.i360designsite.com/Home.aspx) has nothing to do with the code you posted.  It is a Google Maps API v2 map (even though it calls for v1).  Code below.  The marker is exactly where the code puts it at Latitude = "37.0625", Longitude = "-95.677068", which is [somewhere in Kansas](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=37.0625,-95.677068&geocode=1&zoom=10).  Note that the v2 API is deprecated and could stop working as early as May 2013.

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=1&key=AIzaSyCsOdhbicIzYAIw7446dYmhHBGjmpZiS48"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 12);

            map.setUIToDefault();

            var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
            baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
            baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
            baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
            baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
            baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);


            var myLatitude = "37.0625";
            var myLongitude = "-95.677068";
            var strStorename = "Howell Sand Co Inc";
            var strAddress1 = "2300 East Hastings Avenue, Amarillo, TX 79108 (806) 383-1721";
            var strURL = document.getElementById('dnn_hdfStoreURL').value;


            var URL = "";
            if (strURL != "") {
                URL = "<tr><td><b>URL:</b></td><td><a href=\"" + strURL + "\">" + strURL + " </a></td></tr>";
            }
            var point = new GLatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);

            map.setCenter(point, 12);


            var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
            letteredIcon.image = "images/howellsandpointer.png";

            // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
            markerOptions = { icon: letteredIcon };
            var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);

            GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(
                                           "<html><body style=\"font-size: 8px;\"><table><tr><td align='left'><b>Company:</b> </td><td>Howell Sand Co Inc.<br/></td></tr>" +
                                                    "<tr><td style=\"vertical-align:top;\"><b>Address:</b> </td><td>2300 East Hastings Avenue,<br/> Amarillo, TX 79108 (806) 383-1721 </td>" +
                                                    "</tr></body></html>");
            });
            map.addOverlay(marker);
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize();
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this.  In your above code fix, should I remove the myLatitude and myLongitude statements?  How do I wire this up to render inside my map div ?

Comment: Assuming you want the marker at [2300 Hastings Ave, Amarillo, TX](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108&geocode=1&zoom=17&type=m), you probably want to set them to 35.249369,-101.807561

Comment: In your map satement, should I set getElementById to 'map' given that I want to ender the map in a div with class = map?

Comment: That code is from your page.  It isn't mine.  It doesn't matter what the class of the div is.  It is the id that matters, and that needs to match.

Answer (score 0):

There is extraneous whitespace in the URL.  Remove it.

```
<iframe width="310" height="226" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?  f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=Howell+Sand+Co+INC++2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108,+United+State+of+America+(806)+383-1721&amp;daddr=&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=ddw0&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>


<iframe width="310" height="226" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=Howell+Sand+Co+INC++2300+East+Hastings+Avenue+Amarillo,+TX+79108,+United+State+of+America+(806)+383-1721&amp;daddr=&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=49.624204,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=ddw0&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```